# How do I detect if the current session is an SSH session via bash?

Tags: bash, ssh

I would like to detect whether the current user session is from an SSH connection - that is, whether the user is physically sitting at the computer that hosts the current terminal or whether he is remotely connected through SSH?

Is there an easy way to do this, preferably through a bash-scriptable method?

Comment: you might want to check out this U&L question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9605/how-can-i-detect-if-the-shell-is-controlled-from-ssh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick way would be check if the `SSH_TTY` variable is set:

```
$ ssh lab
$ echo $SSH_TTY 
/dev/pts/22
```

There are a few SSH-related variables set. [Two others](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120080/what-are-ssh-tty-and-ssh-connection) are `SSH_CLIENT` and `SSH_CONNECTION`. Either of them could be used as well.

---

Another way would be to check if an ancestor process is the `sshd` daemon:

```
$ pstree -ps $$
init(1)───sshd(1170)───sshd(14153)───sshd(14225)───bash(24232)───pstree(27281)
```

---

Relevant reading:

- [How can I detect if the shell is controlled from SSH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9605/how-can-i-detect-if-the-shell-is-controlled-from-ssh) - a well-answered question on Unix & Linux.

Comment: Excellent.  This is *exactly* what I was looking for.  I'll keep the question open for a few days, and then if this is still the best answer then I'll accept it.

Comment: @InkBlend sure. I personally use the `SSH_TTY` variable to set custom prompts for SSH sessions.

Comment: example:
    
    if [[ ${SSH_TTY} ]] ; then
         export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
   fi